# How does tomcat handles session between restarts?

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat

Consider a tomcat server running with 10 sessions in it. These sessions were started at different times. Then server was restarted. What shall happen at server start-up? Will it "look" (or just look) up sessions which were saved to the disk ? If so, what shall happen after that?

1. If session expires for some user; does tomcat send session invalidated event?
2. Does tomcat check all sessions for invalidation? If yes, when shall it happen and how can I check and notify this? If no session validation is done, what shall happen with live sessions, how long they shall they remain live?

Answer (score 1):

Answering your questions in a slightly different order. This answer assumes a default Tomcat configuration - i.e. one using the StandardManager with the default options.

The persisted sessions include the last active time.
When Tomcat starts, it starts each of the web applications. During web application start, a web application starts its associated session manager.

When the session manager starts, it loads the persisted sessions for that web application. As each session is loaded the session activation event will be fired. Also, the last active time is checked to see if the session needs to be expired. If it does, the session is expired at that point and Tomcat fires the standard session destroyed event.

Once the web application is started, the background thread periodically checks the session last active time and expires sessions as necessary.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, by the way could you please provide a link to documentation where it is described?